# Map gene IDs to Ensembl gene ID

Tags: gene

Forgive me if this question is too trivial.

I have the gene IDs of the following type

```
EOG6STSR2
EOG60ZRJB
EOG6SBFJ2
EOG6P5KX3
EOG6B5PRW
```

from the first supplementary file in [Comparative validation of the D. melanogaster modENCODE transcriptome annotation](http://genome.cshlp.org/content/suppl/2014/05/21/gr.159384.113.DC1.html) .

I'm not sure as to the type of the IDs. I learned that IDs beginning with *EOG* are *Eukaryotic Orthologous Group* IDs but I couldn't find these particular ones in any of the databases.

Is it possible to map them to *Ensembl* IDs or any of the other commonly used ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not gene ids, but groups of orthologous genes -- try to search for the ids on Google, I can find this page http://cegg.unige.ch/orthodb6/fasta.fasta?ogs=EOG6STSR2&swaptree= and thus you should be able to download the sequences and ids from [OrthoDB](http://cegg.unige.ch/orthodb6/).

Note that, strictly speaking, the are no Ensembl ids for Drosophila, only FlyBase ids that are also used by Ensembl.